# Sending Google Cloud notification to MS Teams is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, microsoft-teams, webhooks

i'm a newbie in GCP. I'm trying to send log notification to MS Teams via Google alert Webhooks notification channel. The Email channel is working but not Webhooks channel. Am i missing something?  Maybe permissions??

I have the following settings:

- a log sink to collect the fail logs in Dataform & Workflows and destination to the pub/sub topic.
- pub/sub topic&subscription
- monitoring alert: Email channel+ pub/sub channel + Webhooks channel (MS Teams); log query: resource.type="dataform.googleapis.com/Repository"
  severity=ERROR
- Workflows, Dataform (all working and log explorer can see all logs)
- permission: Pub/Sub Publisher to monitoring service account xxxx@gcp-sa-monitoring-notification.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  I'm not sure what permissions to give which service accounts?
- Cloud function:
  created in the console. trigger with pub/sub subscription. Runtime is using NodeJS 18. pass in the WEBHOOK_URL and MS Teams webhook url in Runtime environment variables

```
const request = require('request');
    const webhookURL = process.env.WEBHOOK_URL;
    exports.subscriber = (pubSubEvent, context) => {

      
        const age = Date.now() - Date.parse(context.timestamp);
        if (age > 60*60*1000) {
            return;
        }
       
        let body = Buffer.from(pubSubEvent.data, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
        const options = {
           
            url: webhookURL,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                //'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('username:password').toString('base64')
            },
            body: body,
        };

        req = request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                throw new Error(err);
            }
            if (res.statusCode != 200) {
                console.error(body);
                throw new Error(res.StatusMessage);
            }
        });
    };
```

In the logs, it shows
Summary or Text is required.
and
Exception from a finished function: Error
I'm not sure what these mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Incoming Webhooks help in posting messages from apps to Teams. If Incoming Webhooks are enabled for a team in any channel, it exposes the HTTPS endpoint, that accepts correctly formatted JSON and inserts the messages to that channel. For example, you can create an Incoming Webhook in your DevOps channel, configure your build, and simultaneously deploy and monitor services to send alerts.

Comment: Reference doc-1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-notifications-to-teams?tabs=data-factory

Comment: Thank you for replying, @Sayali-MSFT. I've successfully implemented before i saw your messages. It's working.